# Book With "Strangest Jigsaw Puzzle Ever" Cover

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult, horror

I'm looking for a book of short horror stories. It would have been a young adult book from the 80s (it was in my hands around '85).  The cover was a rendition of the "Strangest Jigsaw Puzzle Ever" short story [here](https://www.quotev.com/story/1789263/Scary-Stories/6) with the girl putting the jigsaw puzzle together and the face in the window behind her.

Comment: Thereare some good details here, but we might need a little more. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if you can [edit] in any details you remember.

Comment: The jigsaw story you relate looks to have originally been posted in 2010 (http://www.everythingscary.com/story/the-strangest-jigsaw-puzzle.html). Are you certain that it's this exact story?

Comment: If you're not looking for the exact story, it's older, having been told around the campfire in the film, "Dead Poet's Society" in 1989.

Comment: I'm not even sure that story is in the book (and that version is different from the one I'm familiar with if it is).  I am sure the story was the cover; the cover showed the girl and the guy in the window behind her.

Comment: The author is Jason Ryan Qualls https://twitter.com/JASON4VOORHEES2/status/844932914135621634

Comment: So, not the illustration at https://i.ytimg.com/vi/N3ycxoWaWDo/hqdefault.jpg?

Comment: No, this was a full color cover, with the girl facing the view, window and face behind her.

Comment: The odds are decent you're thinking of J.B. Stamper's version in *Tales for the Midnight Hour*
 (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/137747.Tales_for_the_Midnight_Hour) but the covers don't have the puzzle being assembled. I checked other books by the author, but no dice.

Comment: O just got that book in the mail today. I definitely read it as a kid, because I remember the story "The Ten Claws". But as you say, that's not the cover U remember.

Answer (score 1):

Suuper late reply, but I was looking for this EXACT same story, and I think I found it. I believe you're looking for Tales for the midnight hour by Judith Bauer Stamper.

The book came out in 1977. I checked it out of my Catholic School library back in 1992?

https://openlibrary.org/works/OL2193345W/Tales_for_the_midnight_hour

Comment: Hello, welcome to SciFi.SE. Note that *Tales for the Midnight Hour* has already been suggested by someone in the comments, and the OP has said the cover doesn't match what they remember